# Find bounds of a array? C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I was somewhat surprised to see the below work coming from a C++ background.
It obviously holds the bounds information at runtime, how can i get the first and 2nd bounds?

Reflection is welcome but not recommended.

```
    ff(new int[3, 4]);

    static void ff(int[,] a)
    {
        var aa = a[1, 2];
    }
```

Comment: Note that the lower bound is not always 0 as you can create arrays with any lower bound using one overload of Array.CreateInstance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
int bound0 = a.GetUpperBound(0);
int bound1 = a.GetUpperBound(1);
```

Answer (score 3):

You get the largest accessible index for dimension `i` with
`GetUpperBound(i)`.

You get the number of elements for dimension `i` with `GetLength(i)` or `GetLongLength(i)`.

Dimensions start at 0;

Answer (score 2):

Arrays in .net have a number of methods attached to them, amongst these are `GetUpperBound` and `GetLowerBound`:

```
var three = a.GetUpperBound(0); // contents is: 2
var four = a.GetUpperBound(1); // contents is: 3
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.GetUpperBound Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getupperbound.aspx) gets the upper bound of the specified dimension in the Array.:

```
int bound0 = array.GetUpperBound(0);
int bound1 = array.GetUpperBound(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is `GetLength(int dim)` :

```
for (int row = 0; row < a.GetLength(0); row++)
   ...
```

For 1-dimensional arrays the `Length` property is used mostly.